# Convergent successions is a closed set of bounded successions with the supremum distance

Tags: analysis

What I'm trying to prove is the following:
Be $l^{\infty} = \{x = \{x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}: ||x||_{\infty}=sup_n |x_n| < \infty\}$ a metric space using $d(x,y) = ||x-y||_{\infty}$ for $x,y\in l^\infty$. Be $c$ the space of the convergent successions of real numbers. Then $c$ is a closed set of $l^\infty$.

My approach so far looks like this:

Be $\{z_k\}_k \subset c$ a convergent succession, with $\{z_{k,n}\}_n \subset \mathbb{R}$, $z_k \rightarrow z=\{z_n\}_n \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let's see that $z$ is convergent so $z\in c$: Be $\varepsilon > 0$.

Firstly, as $z_n \rightarrow z, \exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall k \geq k_0, d(z_k, z)< \varepsilon / 2$, which, by definition of the distance, means that $\forall k \geq k_0, |z_{k,n} - z_n |< \varepsilon / 2, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $.

Now, my approach would follow by using the inequality
$$
|z_n - a| \leq |z_n - z_{k,n}| + |z_{k,n} - a| < \varepsilon/2 + \varepsilon/2 = \varepsilon, \forall k\geq k_0, n\geq n_0 
$$
where $n_0$ is such that $|z_{k,n} - a | < \varepsilon$ (as $z_{k,n}$ converges because it is from $c$).

The problem is that I don't know how (or is it even true) to prove that all the $z_{k,n}$ converge to the same $a$ for all $k$ (or at least $k$ big enough), and therefore this prove is invalid. My approach to prove this is by using that, as $z_k$ is convergent, it is also Cauchy, and, therefore, for two $k_a, k_b$ big enough, if $z_{k_a,n} \rightarrow a$, then so does $z_{k_b,n} \rightarrow a$, as
$d(z_{k_a,n}, z_{k_b,n}) < \varepsilon /4 \implies |z_{k_a,n} - z_{k_b,n}| < \varepsilon / 4, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, and therefore $|z_{k_b,n} - a| \leq |z_{k_b,n} - z_{k_a,n} + |z_{k_a,n} - a| < \varepsilon/4 + \varepsilon/4 = \varepsilon/2$. Is this approach correct? The main problem I see here is that  depending on the last $k_a$, $a$ could be different and therefore the prove is not solid as $z$ would converge to different values.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the probelm you are facing show that $(z_n)$ is  Cauchy sequence. That is enough to say that it is a convergent sequence.

Use the inequality $|z_n-z_m| \leq |z_{k,n}-z_{k,m}|+|z_{k,n}-z_n|+|z_m-z_{k,m}|$. Can you finish?

Comment: Ah, that's right, I can use that in this case because $(z_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers, right? This makes it much easier, thank you!